# Vim opening files in replace mode when .vimrc has 'set paste'

Tags: vim

When I did copy-paste in vim, the indentation was not correct.  So I added the following to .vimrc

```
set paste
```

Now the paste works fine, but vim is opening files in replace mode.  why is that?

What are my alternatives?

Thanks

Comment: Adding `set paste` into my `.vimrc` does not open files in replace mode. Maybe include your `.vimrc` file? Also, are you using gui or terminal?

Comment: The console is in a web browser(chrome) window.

Comment: Can't really do anything without a `.vimrc` file. Putting `set paste` does not open files in replace mode for me. Try removing everything out of your `.vimrc` file except for `set paste` and see if it still opens files in replace mode. If not, then it's something in your `.vimrc` file doing it.

Answer (score 0):

What I do to avoid indentation problems is to use `:[line]pu[t] [x]`. for example, if I want to paste X lines after line 4 I will do:

```
:4put+
```

From `:help :put`

```
 :[line]pu[t] [x]        Put the text [from register x] after [line] (default
                         current line).  This always works linewise, thus 
                         this command can be used to put a yanked block as new
                         lines.
```